# Are these positive semidefinite matrices invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

Suppose $n \ge 2$ and we have an $n \times n$ Hermitian, positive semidefinite matrix with $1$ down the main diagonal, and all off-diagonal entries have modulus strictly less than $\frac{1}{n-1}$. Can we conclude that this matrix is invertible? Moreover, can this upper bound of $\frac{1}{n-1}$ be improved?

This is a question inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2522979/inner-product-smallness-condition-for-linear-independence-of-unit-vectors). I have a suspicion that this can be done with Gram matrices, but I don't have the skill with these matrices to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true as a consequence of the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).  Another approach that gives us the same result: we can note that if $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ denotes the [induced $\infty$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms), then $\|M - I\|_\infty < 1$ (since the matrices are Hermitian, it's also equivalent to use the induced $1$-norm)

A stronger sufficient condition is that (assuming the diagonal entries are still all $1$) the non-diagonal entries of each row must have absolute values with sum strictly less than $1$.

Comment: Thank you, this is *exactly* what I wanted. :-)